# Why no mobile view?

Tags: discussion, ios, mobile

Being intrinsically Apple-centric, why does apple.stackexchange.com not have a mobile view for my iPhone?

The likelyhood of an Apple user coming to this site is high right? So why would you not want a mobile version of apple.stackexchange.com, explicitly optimised for iOS devices?

Comment: This should be on Meta. Duplicate: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278/ase-mobile-site

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this application for iPhone: [Six to Eight](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/six-to-eight/id384094708?mt=8)

Answer (score 1):

Check http://stackapps.com for iOS and OS X apps.

Beyond that, we do have a rudimentary mobile theme at the moment that was just deployed. Browse from iPhone to see it.

Comment: just tried apple.stackexchange.com on the mobile. no change?

Comment: Works for me, it's just a simplified UI with less fuss. Better performance on my phone

Comment: It's not working for me now.. not sure they reverted the changes from mobile view or not ?

Comment: @garik I see it on my iPhone 4, what device are you using? Note that we no longer consider iPad a mobile device (more correctly..)

Comment: mine is iPhone 3GS